# Dynamically Generate Nav Bar in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

I am wondering what the best way would be to change my nav bar based on where a user is on the site.

I am thinking there will be 3 different states of my nav bar.

1. Non Logged in users
2. Logged in users
3. Admin Area

I am using Mobx, Reactjs and ReactRouter

I will have components like this

```
@inject("routingStore")
@observer
export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>test routing</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I was thinking of making my Nav into a component then check the url if it would be something like

`localhost:8080/test-area` (could mean they are not logged in or logged in, would do further checking to see if say session storage with the auth token was set or not)

or

```
locahost:8080/admin/test
```

I would somehow check for "/admin" and load up the correct nav.

I however not sure how to get the stuff to re-render as I am not sure if switching between "links" will cause anything that is checking the "react-router" stuff to re-render.

Comment: was the below answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a broad answer because you've asked a broad question. You seem to be asking for guidance before you build too much, and so an exact answer is not possible here.

Basially, I would use state to determine the appearance and options displayed on the Navbar, as opposed to route. However, you should be to access both route and state as needed.

In your app state, you should track whether a user is logged in or not, and what type of role they are operating in. I don't know how mobx works, though I know how I'd do it with redux.

You should not have to worrying about re-rendering anything if you are using react, react-router, and your state correctly. React will re-render if state or props change.

So, based on state, the main, or top-level component which includes the navbar component can determine whether to show the navbar, and the navbar component itself can also access state and determine what parts of the navbar to show.

So somewhere in your app, with `mobx` you'll create a current user state object (I think, this is something of a guess because I've not used that package for storing state, nevertheless I persist):

```
import { observable } from "mobx"

class CurrentUser {
    id = Math.random();
    @observable isAuthenticated = false;
    @observable role = '';
}
```

Then you will use that through out, something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import NavBar from '../NavBar' // your NavBar component
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

@observer
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
          {this.props.store.isAuthenticated &&
           <NavBar />}
        </div>
    }
}

const store = new CurrentUser();
ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.getElementById('mount'));
```

In like manner, you can use `role` to make conditions in your components, and you can do the same with other components, such as the NavBar.

Comment: Hey there? i won't be using redux can you suggest where to store the state globally

Comment: My problem is the same as OP's but I will be having static navbar I like to show some navbar's when the user logged in if you are using actively let me know will discuss